# how can a scripter create windows applications?

Tags: windows

I want to try something new, rather than make web servers do and respond, i thought what if i can create an application that runs on directly on my operating system, and it struck me that it could be quite fun and useful.

I am familiar with only scripting languages like php, ruby, javascript.

I have learned VBA and C, but haven't used it much.

I want to know, what is a fast and easy way to develop applications on windows ?

how has people been making desktop applications in the past and now ?

Also, is there a simple way to support Mac or Linux as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already familiar with Ruby, You should check out [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/).

It is a first class citizen of the programming languages you can use to communicate with the Windows API.

I don't think it comes bundled in the standard Visual Studio. You may have to download and install separately.

Also, VBA is a particularly old technology and dare I say, is a horrible language; better chuck it and use its modern counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at IronPython which may be an easy transition for you as well.

C# will also be an easy language to pick up from what you have used in the past.

If you want to stay in scripting land you can look at Powershell which is a mix of .NET and commandline inteface.

Answer (score 1):

I'd grab Tcl/Tk, since you mentioned ruby.  It has Ruby bindings.

Comment: I'd go with Tcl/Tk regardless of Ruby. It's the simplest way of creating a GUI that works seamlessly on Unix, Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using IE.

[VBScript Forms](http://jansfreeware.com/articles/vbs-forms.html)

> You can run VBScripts under the
>   windows scripting host and use
>   internet explorer for the graphical
>   user interface (GUI). The code in the
>   Code section provides a framework for
>   building windows like application
>   using vbscript+ie. Because the script
>   running under the scripting host is
>   not restricted you have full access to
>   the file system and can create objects
>   to access text files, databases etc.